# Project online update custom filed via MS power automate

Tags: sharepoint, odata, ms-project, power-automate

I have a problem with MS project online string custom field using

[Send an HTTP request to SharePoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWqg1.jpg)

but initially after project was created the field is empty checking on (after checkout)
`_api/ProjectServer/Projects('ProjectUid')/draft/includecustomfields`
it does not appear.
 
If I set data on this field on PWA save it and publish the above action work and I can update it.
In short how can I update this field when it's empty using MS power automate actions ?

Comment: are you trying to update a custom field for the project? Or are you trying to update a custom task field within a project?

Comment: custom field for the project

Comment: ahhh, thats the only problem I have too. I  have a custom Field for our PWA site that I can't seem to get. I can updates customs fields for a task in a project, but not custom fields in a project for PWA Home page. Hopefully someone can assist us